# Declare "typedef int (*x)(void *)" in java with GraalVM

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to consume a C library with GraalMV and I have the following struct I don't find how to declare:

```
typedef int (*mon_handler)(void *);

typedef struct
{
  mon_handler mon_cb;

} opts;
```

I need to know with which data type declare **mon_handler**

```
@CStruct(value="opts")
interface Opts extends Pointerbase{
  
  @CField("mon_handler")
  ???????? getMonHandler();
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the typecasting of the void pointer this simplifies to

```c
typedef int *mon_handler;
```

Where `mon_handler` is a pointer to an `int`.  It's essentially equivalent to

```c
typedef (int *) mon_handler;
```

So the correct mapping would be `IntByReference` in JNA.  [`CIntPointer`](https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/index.html?org/graalvm/nativeimage/c/type/CIntPointer.html) in GraalVM also matches this type:

> A pointer to a 32-bit C primitive value.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the answer. Do you know if IntByReference could be equivalent to the CIntPointer from graalvm ?

Comment: Yes, [CIntPointer](https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/index.html?org/graalvm/nativeimage/c/type/CIntPointer.html) is "A pointer to a 32-bit C primitive value." which is exactly what this is.